# SELinux Regression Test Failing

Tags: linux, selinux, testing

I have cloned the selinux-testsuite regression tests from: https://github.com/SELinuxProject/selinux-testsuite

I am running the tests in a CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core) VM. Which I don't believe to be relevant.

SELinux is enforcing using the targeted policy before I install the temporary test policies using:

`make -C policy load`

sestatus says

```
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Max kernel policy version:      31
```

I believe I have followed the instructions for running the testsuite accurately. However when I run it I see a single failure:

```
[snipped OK messages]

bounds/test ................. ok     
nnp_nosuid/test ............. ok     
mmap/test ................... 1/47 # Failed test 27 in mmap/test at line 143
#  mmap/test line 143 is:     ok($result);
mmap/test ................... Failed 1/47 subtests 
unix_socket/test ............ ok   
inet_socket/test ............ ok     

[more snipped OK messages]

Test Summary Report
-------------------
mmap/test                 (Wstat: 0 Tests: 47 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  27
Files=51, Tests=520, 35 wallclock secs ( 0.11 usr  0.04 sys +  0.77 cusr  0.94 csys =  1.86 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/51 test programs. 1/520 subtests failed.
```

I isolated the problematic test from the mmap test group to:

```
#!/bin/bash

basedir=$(pwd)/tests/mmap

if [ ! -d $basedir ]; then
    printf "Error: missing basedir: $basedir\n"
    exit 1
fi

# Clean up from prior runs.
rm -f $basedir/temp_file

# Create temporary file.
dd if=/dev/zero of=$basedir/temp_file count=8 2>&1 > /dev/null
printf "\ncreate: OK\n"
chcon -t test_mmap_file_t $basedir/temp_file
printf "\nchcon: OK\n"

if [ ! -f $basedir/mmap_file_shared ]; then
    printf "Error - missing executable: $basedir/mmap_file_shared\n"
    exit 1
fi

if [ ! -f $basedir/temp_file ]; then
    printf "Error - missing temp file: $basedir/temp_file\n"
    exit 1
fi

/bin/runcon -t test_no_map_t -- $basedir/mmap_file_shared $basedir/temp_file
```

Which generates the AVC message in /var/log/audit/audit.log:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1556563573.950:2466): avc:  denied  { search } for  pid=16708 comm="mmap_file_share" name="vagrant" dev="dm-0" ino=81922 scontext=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:test_no_map_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
```

I'm not entirely sure if this AVC is intended (as a negative testacase) by the testsuite. But I would like to understand this failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to close the loop on this the answer was provided by Ondrej Mosnacek of the selinux mailing list:

Quoth Ondrej:

> RHEL and CentOS 7.6 have the domain_can_mmap_files SELinux boolean set
>   to "on" by default
>   [[1]](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html-single/7.6_release_notes/index#BZ1460322),
>   which basically means that map permissions are not checked, which
>   logically leads to the failure of the test that checks that map
>   permission is denied when it was not allowed by the test policy. When
>   running the testsuite on CentOS/RHEL 7.6, you need to turn off the
>   domain_can_mmap_files boolean during test execution.

To solve it I did:

```
# Get the original value of the bool
export OLD_MMAP_BOOL=$(getsebool domain_can_mmap_files | awk '{ print $3 }')
# Disable it
sudo setsebool domain_can_mmap_files off
# Run the test suite
make -C tests test
# Restore the previous state
sudo OLD_MMAP_BOOL=$OLD_MMAP_BOOL setsebool domain_can_mmap_files $OLD_MMAP_BOOL
```

Comment: Thank you for providing the detailed answer.